# How to dynamically update data in datagridview based on keystroke from user?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keystroke

I am writing a program that uses a text box that the user can type into in order to search a data set of "staff".

The data from the "Staf" table is displayed in the data grid but i want the data grid to update as the user types into the search text box.

I can't figure it out i'm sure its simple and easy to solve but i need help please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code what have you tried so far so it would be easy to suggest. My Suggestion is write a function in such a way it fetches the required data based on your search and update the data to your grid

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle text changed event of the filter textbox (assuming that your datagrdview is databound):

```
private void textBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Replace your field here
    (dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);
}
```